# What is the prefColumnCount property for a TextField?

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I'm reading the docs for [TextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html#prefColumnCountProperty), and I came across a property called prefColumnCount. From what I understand, this property controls the size of the text field, but I can't find a definitive answer, and googling yields nothing. What is a text column? How are they measured? Is there anything that isn't obvious that I should know?

Comment: It's (approximately) the number of characters. (Approximately because in most fonts the physical width depends on the actual characters that appear in the text.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `TextFieldSkin` you can find this code snippet using the property:

```
@Override
protected double computePrefWidth(double height, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset) {
    TextField textField = getSkinnable();

    double characterWidth = fontMetrics.get().computeStringWidth("W");

    int columnCount = textField.getPrefColumnCount();

    return columnCount * characterWidth + leftInset + rightInset;
}
```

I.e. it's used to compute the preferred width by multiplying the value of the property with the width of a `W` and adding the horizontal insets.