# JavaFX TextField resize with monospace font

Tags: java, javafx

I want to make a TextField that automatically resizes to the size of its content. If I use `textField.prefColumnCountProperty().bind(textField.textProperty().length());` it works.
But as soon as I use a monospaced font the TextField resizes but the text is invisible until I select it. How can I use the resize property with a monospaced font?

**Before selecting the text:**

[image: Before selecting the text]

**After selecting the text:**

[image: After selecting the text]

**Main.java**

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Controller.java**

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;


public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TextField textField;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        textField.setStyle("-fx-font-family: 'monospaced';");
        textField.prefColumnCountProperty().bind(textField.textProperty().length());
    }

}
```

**sample.fxml**

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
        <TextField fx:id="textField"></TextField>
</GridPane>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short:**

The problem only occurs when [`getAlignment()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html#getAlignment--) is set to left ([`BASELINE_LEFT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Pos.html#BASELINE_LEFT), [`BOTTOM_LEFT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Pos.html#BOTTOM_LEFT), [`CENTER_LEFT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Pos.html#CENTER_LEFT) or [`TOP_LEFT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Pos.html#TOP_LEFT)) so just use `textField.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);`.

---

**Long answer since this is still a strange behavior:**

The text is positioned incorrectly, all the text is moved to the left out of the visible area. It seems like the cause of this behavior is that the width of the textfield is to small.

[image]

This is a small example where the text "test" is typed and then moves the cursor to the left.

---

Well i guess it's a problem how `TextFieldSkin.computePrefWidth` works, since it doesn't calculate the size of the cursor.

You could create your own TextFieldSkin which computePrefWidth returns a bigger value: (This code-sample uses `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin.TextFieldSkin` for Java-8)

```
textField.setSkin(new TextFieldSkin(textField){
    @Override
    protected double computePrefWidth(double height, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset) {
        return 1 + super.computePrefWidth(height, topInset, rightInset, bottomInset, leftInset);
    }
});
```

You could also one to the `prefColumnCount`

```
textField.prefColumnCountProperty().bind(textField.textProperty().length().add(1));
```

---

Also see: [What is the prefColumnCount property for a TextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43398185/8097737)

Comment: Looks like you're right and computePrefWidth returns values too small.
Have you got an idea why selecting the text solves the problem?

Comment: The text is moved to the left out of the visible area. You could also move the cursor to the left to see next character.

Comment: Hmm..But then it's more like the text is positioned wrong. The textfield has the correct size but the text is still invisible because it's to far on the left.

Comment: Yes, the text is positioned wrong, but i can't find anything to get or change the "textposition". You could try to move the caret.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try further. Is it worth filing a bug report for this?

Comment: @JohnyDoe it seems like the problem only occurs when [`getAlignment`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html#getAlignment--) is set to left. You could also just use for example `textField.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);` and the text is always visible.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted =D Please add it to your answer and I'll accept it :)